# Form submission is not accepting parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, file-upload

I have a form that contains a file input field and 2 buttons with `name="action"` and values as `'sign'` and `'verify'` respectively.
I am trying to get that file and parameter of buttons upon submitting the form
But my controller is not receiving the parameters and its giving `null`.

**This my controller code for the URL Mapping of my form action:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/secure/pqca/verifydoc")
public String verifiedDoc(@RequestParam("form_action") String form_action, 
                          @RequestParam("document") MultipartFile file, 
                          Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    
    System.out.print("hiii   " + request.getParameter("form_action"));
    pqcaService.verifiedDoc(form_action, file, model, request);
    return "pqca/verifyDocument";
}
```

**This is form:**

```html
<form id="add_sign_form" 
      action="/pqra/secure/pqca/verifydoc"
      method="post" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input type="file"
               name="document"
               path="doc"
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="document"
               maxlength="50" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" 
            id="add_sign" 
            name="form_action" 
            value="sign"
            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary login-submit-cs" 
            style="margin-top:  10px">
        Add Signature
    </button>

    <button type="submit" 
            id="verify_sign" 
            name="form_action"
            value="verify"
            lass="btn btn-sm btn-primary login-submit-cs"
            style="margin-top: 10px">
        Verify Signature
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you want to get a controller parameters if you are not sending them?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did't understand, please elloborate.

Answer (score 0):

Your form submission is not accepting parameters because you are not sending them.

The request to the controller is `POST`, that contains `multipart/form-data` MIME type. In this way it could be parsed by parts. Some of them should include form data values stored from input fields. But you use `<button>` value to store a required parameter value. This element is not added to the form data because it is not an `<input>` field. Instead, you should use `<input type="submit">` for the button or buttons with the hidden input field. When the button is clicked set the value of the hidden field.

```html
     <input type="submit" 
            id="add_sign" 
            name="form_action" 
            value="sign"
            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary login-submit-cs" 
            style="margin-top:  10px">
        Add Signature
    
    <input type="submit" 
            id="verify_sign" 
            name="form_action"
            value="verify"
            lass="btn btn-sm btn-primary login-submit-cs"
            style="margin-top: 10px">
        Verify Signature
```

Or

```html
     <button type="submit" 
            id="add_sign" 
            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary login-submit-cs" 
            style="margin-top:  10px"
            onclick="this.form.form_action='sign'">
        Add Signature
    </button>

    <button type="submit" 
            id="verify_sign" 
            lass="btn btn-sm btn-primary login-submit-cs"
            style="margin-top: 10px"    
            onclick="this.form.form_action='verify'">
        Verify Signature
    </button>

    <input type="hidden"
            name="form_action">
```